# Reference Xml file from Zip archive

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I want to transform `Xml` document located in `Zip` archive, in this particular case it's `Docx` (OpenXML) Zip file archive. While I was searching for an answer, I read about [jar protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-0913/author/jar.html#jarprotocol) suggested couple of times (for example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012932/read-a-remote-zipped-xml-with-just-xsl/3013535#3013535)). After trying various combinations or slashes, backslashes and prefixes I finally got Saxon output something else that "File does not exist", i.e.:

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\SaxonHE9\saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform ^
    -xsl:style-transform.xslt ^
    -s:file:///c:/temp/test.docx!/word/document.xml ^
    -o:test_out.xml
```

outputs this:

```
Warning: at xsl:stylesheet on line 14 column 19 of style-transform.xslt:
  Running an XSLT 1 stylesheet with an XSLT 2 processor
Error
  I/O error reported by XML parser processing
  file:///c:/temp/test.docx!/word/document.xml:
  c:\temp\test.docx!\word\document.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

which is quite different then output from my previous attempts, when I assume I wasn't using correct reference to Zip file resource.

Does someone know what may be this issue here, or more generally provide working example of using Xml file from Zip archive as Xml source for transformation with Saxon?

Comment: Does 's:jar:file:///c:/temp/test.docx!/word/document.xml` work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, that was one of the first things I tried and got just:  `Source file jar:file:\c:\temp\test.docx!\word\document.xml does not exist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the file name to Saxom as a url using the -u option, for example

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -u jar:file:./YOURINPUTARCHIVE.ods\!/content.xml YOURXSLT.xslt
```

This works for me on linux.

Best, Ruprecht

Comment: Thanks Ruprecht, your suggestion works perfectly on Windows too :)

Comment: I put the xslt file in a zip, and use the zip path as your style, It can work too. If I encrypt the xslt zip file , how to make the path with  password ?