Using Saxon Parser, how do I define a source file that's within a zip file?
I'm basing my attempts to resolve my problem on the answer in this thread, but I'm having no luck.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18558641/7115040?stw=2
This is response appears the most relevant I've been able to find.
Im running it as part of a AutoHotKey routine within Windows, but I'm also unable to get it to run successfully from a command line.
The default folder is set with this line. All relevant files (except Saxon) are in that folder.
SetWorkingDir E:\dwgs\Json\ORR Stations Table1410

This run line returns an 'Invalid URI' error:
runwait %comspec% /k java -jar "C:\Program Files\My Small Programs\Saxon\saxon-he-12.5.jar" -u jar:"file:./ORR Stations Table1410.zip\!/ORR Stations Table1410.xml" -xsl:"ORR Table 1410 Compare with NR.xsl" -o:"ORR Table 1410 Compare with NR OUT.xml"

What is the correct syntax?
Edited to show folder listings as requested:
If I run the uncompressed .xml file using the following, it works as expected:
-s:"ORR Stations Table1410.xml" 




The following worked for me on Mac (on one line):
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -xsl:test.xsl -u 
  -s:jar:file:///Users/mike/Downloads/Archive.zip!/africa.xml -t

I don't have a Windows machine handy to try it on; different shells have different rules for escaping special characters.
Now adding spaces to the names, I find that the following works:
-u -s:"jar:file:///Users/mike/Downloads/Archive%202/Archive.zip!/south%20america.xml"

It also works without the quotes around the URI.
And if Downloads is the current directory, I can also do
-u -s:jar:file:Archive%202/Archive.zip!/south%20america.xml


After a /lot/ of trial and error, this is the solution that works for me (All on one line).
runwait java -jar "C:\Program Files\My Small Programs\Saxon\saxon-he-12.5.jar"
-u jar:file:ORR`%20Stations`%20Table1410.zip!/ORR`%20Stations`%20Table1410.xml
-xsl:ORR`%20Table`%201410`%20Compare`%20with`%20NR.xsl
-o:"ORR Table 1410 Compare with NR OUT.xml" 


No double quotes for the input files.
No path required.
Substitute spaces with %20.
AutoHotKey requires a backtick to escape %. If running from a Windows command box these need to be removed.
The -s: source option isn't required as -u appears to be a substitute.


I would try -s:"ORR Stations Table1410.zip?select=ORR Stations Table1410.xml".
Or for the jar: URI attempt try to use %20 where you have spaces: -u jar:"file:./ORR%20Stations%20Table1410.zip\!/ORR%20Stations%20Table1410.xml. But on testing I find that only an absolute file URI in the jar URI works e.g.  java -jar 'C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE12-5J\saxon-he-12.5.jar' -t -u -xsl:./identity-xslt3-mode.xsl -s:'jar:file:///C:/Users/marti/OneDrive/Documents/xslt/blog-xslt-3-by-example/jar-zip-uri-test/sample%20file%201.zip!/sample%20file%201.xml' works.

That's returning 'Source file ORR Stations Table1410.zip?select=ORR Stations Table1410.xml does not exist' I've double checked for spelling & that the file(s) exists.
